# Вывод в столбец js

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, json, reactjs

Столкнуля с следующей проблемы:
Есть файл `json` следующего вида:

```
"type": "Mazda (с 2012-05-05)\n" +
        "Opel (с 2012-05-05)\n" +
        "Jaguar (с 2012-11-07)\n",
```

Кроме этих трех будет n-ое число.
Идея в том, что первончально мы видим только первую строку:`Mazda (с 2012-05-05)`, все остальные скрыты. По нажатию на кнопку нужно развернуть весь список, что бы текст был не в строчку а в столбец, каждая позиция в своё теге. У меня получается сделать только в строчку и в один тег запихнуть

```js
const cars = {
  "type": "Mazda (с 2012-05-05)\n" +
    "Opel (с 2012-05-05)\n" +
    "Jaguar (с 2012-11-07)\n",
};


function show() {
  document.getElementById("hideCars").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("btnShow").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("btnHide").style.display = "block";
}


function hide() {
  document.getElementById("hideCars").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("btnShow").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("btnHide").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#hideCars {
  display: none;
}

#btnHide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Машины:
<br>биби
<div id="hideCars">
  for (var i=1; i
  < cars.type.lenght;i++){ cars.type.split( "\n").[a] } </div>
    <button id="btnShow" onclick="show()">Показать все</button>
    <button id="btnHide" onclick="hide()">Скрыть все</button>
```

Comment: _Есть файл json следующего вида..._ Вообще то это не json, и не файл, а просто JS-объект

Comment: с таким ником вы должны уже были разработать свой собственный язык программирования и нас учить ему =) Во первых вы вставили кусок javascript прямо в верстку без тега <script> , он у вас и выводится на экран, этот цикл и должен печатать блоки, как мы понимаем? правильно?

Comment: Знаю, сейчас подумаю как переформулировать вопрос

Comment: Dmitry прав, на счёт цикла который должен печатать блоки

Comment: Вы не можете использовать цикл `for` в JSX, как и любые блоки (statements), только выражения. Похоже вам нужно начать с [азов](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const DATA = {
  carList: [
    {name: 'Mazda', text: '(с 2012-05-05)'},
    {name: 'Opel', text: '(с 2012-05-05)'},
    {name: 'Jaguar', text: '(с 2012-11-07)'},
  ]
};
const CAR_LIST_ID = '#car-list';
const TOOGLER_ID = '#toogler';

for (let carIndex in DATA.carList) {
    let currentCar = DATA.carList[carIndex];
    renderCar(currentCar, CAR_LIST_ID)
}

function renderCar(car, parentId) {
  if (!car || !parentId) {return;}
  $(parentId).append(`<li><p><strong> ${car.name}</strong><span>${car.text}</span></p></li>`);
}

jQuery(document).on('click.toogleCarList',TOOGLER_ID, (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let $currentButton = $(event.currentTarget),
      $carListElement = $(CAR_LIST_ID);
  $carListElement.slideToggle(300,function(){
    $currentButton.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Скрыть тачки' : 'Показать тачки');
  });
});
```

```css
.car-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Машины: <button id="toogler">Показать тачки</button></p>
<ul id="car-list" class="car-list"></ul>
```